# Segfault in Cygwin but not VS, any ideas?

Tags: c++

It works with Visual Studio, but segfaults in Cygwin, which is weird because I'm compiling the same source, and both generate a Windows executable. GDB doesn't work very well for me in Cygwin for some reason, and the error doesn't appear in VS so I can't really debug it there.

Any ideas?

```
int main(void)
{
    Pair ***occurences = new Pair**[20];

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        occurences[i] = new Pair*[i+1];

        for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
        {
            occurences[i][j] = new Pair[26];

            for (k = 0; k < 26; k++)
            {
                Pair pair;
                pair.c = k + 'a';
                pair.occurs = 0;
                occurences[i][j][k] = pair;
            }
        }
    }

    std::fstream sin;
    sin.open("dictionary.txt");
    std::string word;

    while (std::getline(sin, word))
    {
        if (word.size() < 21)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
            {
                // SEGFAULTING HERE
                occurences[word.size()-1][i][word[i] - 'a'].occurences++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
        {
            delete [] occurences[i][j];
        }
        delete [] occurences[i];
    }
    delete [] occurences;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that no line is longer then 20 characters? And btw, don't use magic numbers, use `word[i] - '0'` or `word[i] - 'A'` or whatever instead.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: "&& i <= 20", and fixed

Comment: did you try compiling in debug mode in VS, and enabling all runtime checks?

Comment: @arasmussen How is that related? You are accessing `occurrences[word.size()-1]`

Comment: Are you sure there are only lower case letters of English alphabet in your dictionary? No spaces, digits and such? Try: grep [^a-z] dictionary.txt

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Sorry, it's supposed to be "&& word.size() <= 20", problem still persists. @cababunga: My dictionary is 100% lower case letters.

Comment: @arasmussen Because now you have a problem with `i`, you are allocating `1,2,3,4,5,...` elements for the second dimension, but you will access always `0..19`, that will of course crash.

Comment: @stijn: I have tried compiling and running in debug mode in VS, but I'm unsure as to how to enable all runtime checks. All of mine are currently set to the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You marked this line as the critical point:

```
occurences[word.size()-1][i][word[i] - 97].occurs++;
```

All three array accesses might go wrong here, and you would have to check them all:

It seems like the first dimension of the array has the length 20, so the valid values for the index are [0..19]. `word.size()-1` will be less than 0 if the size of the word is zero itself, and it will be larger than 19 if the size of the word is 21 or more.

Are you sure the length of the word is always in the range [1..20]?

The second dimension has variable length, depending on the index of the first dimension. Are you sure this never gets out of bound?

The third dimension strikes me as the most obvious. You subtract 97 from the character code, and use the result as index into an array with 26 entries. This assumes that all characters are in the range of [97..122], meaning ['a'..'z']. Are you sure that there will never be other characters in the input? For example, if there are any capital characters, the resulting index will be negative.

Comment: +1 for the second dimention. I was going to write exactly the same.

Comment: @Timbo: And all characters are a lowercase letter.

Comment: @arasmussen What is the value of word when the failure happens?

Comment: I'm not sure, like I said, it's hard to debug using GDB with Cygwin, and the error cannot be reproduced in VS.

Comment: How about you write the value of word to the console before that line? In a world without working debuggers, there is still printf!

Answer (score 1):

Just reformulating my comment as an answer:

`occurences[word.size()-1][i][word[i] - 'a'].occurs++;`

if `word.size()` is 100 (for example) this will crash (for `i == 0`) since `occurences` has only 20 elements.

Comment: Good catch, take a look at the revised code which is still breaking.

Comment: @arasmussen Now you have a problem with second dimension. You are accessing indexes 0..19, but there aren't that many.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Nope, the second dimension has just as many as the first dimension's index. So the 3rd index of the first dimension will have length 3 for the second dimension. Therefore since i < word.size(), and the first dimension is [word.size()-1], then i cannot exceed word.size()-1 which is the length of the second dimension.

Comment: @arasmussen Definitelly not in the code you posted. In your code the second dimmension is increasing in size. Starts at 1, ends at 20 elements.

Comment: @Let_Me_be: Right and if you take a look at my allocation code you'll see that the second dimension allocates i+1 elements where i starts at 0 and goes to 19, therefore describing the behavior that you've mentioned.

Comment: @arasmussen OMG this is pointless. Yes you are allocating `i+1` but you are not accesing just `i+1` elements, you are accessing all 20.